Manga/manhua/manhwa where the female lead is a princess who is reincarnated by the guard who loved her
The female lead, who was one of many princesses in the royal family, was reincarnated back to her younger self before a revolution took place in the land. The guard who loved her at a distance was part of a minority in society that were treated as slaves and ends up becoming the king through marriage with the lead's sister who wants the lead dead. The guard (then king) orders for her reincarnation upon finding out that she had died. The female lead is blond and the guard has black/brown hair. The other princesses are also blond and I can't remember if she had brothers.
It was a few years ago I saw this manga so I apologize for the lacking description.

https://myanimelist.net/anime/52962/Tearmoon_Teikoku_Monogatari__Dantoudai_kara_Hajimaru_Hime_no_Tensei_Gyakuten_Story?

https://www.goodreads.com/series/296807-the-reincarnated-princess-strikes-down-flags-today-as-well-manga?

Is this Revolutionary Princess Eve...?

Princess Evienrose, despite advocating fiercely for the rights of the homunculi rebels, now awaits death at their hands… that is until she is poisoned by her own sister! Awakening eight years in the past, Eve now has one goal: become the Empress and liberate the homunculi to stop the rebellion from ever happening! To do this, she appoints the rebel king himself, Mikaelis Agnito, as her personal knight. But with Eve’s scheming sisters standing in the way, the fight for the crown is on, and the fate of the Hadelamid empire rests in her hands!

The royal family of the Hadelamid Empire used alchemy to create the homunculi, a race of artificial humans bred to serve them. Evienrose Hadelamid, the blonde-haired female lead and seventh princess, was opposed to the mistreatment of the homunculi.



It was customary for each royal to select a homunculus as their personal knight, but Eve refused, as she disapproved of the custom. Mikaelis Agnito, the black-haired male lead and personal knight of Eve's younger sister, Rosenitte, was secretly in love with Eve.
When Mikael heard that Eve was to be forced into an arranged marriage, he led a rebellion of the homunculi to prevent that. Almost all the royals were executed, except for Eve and Rosie, who became the new empress when Mikael became emperor.
Rosie knew Mikael loved Eve, so she persuaded Eve to drink a vial of poison by telling her that she was going to be executed. When Mikael found Eve dead, he was devastated and ordered a sage to turn back time to give her a chance to change her fate.



You can read the full manhwa at Tapas.
